# Android browsers viewport and media queries not working for word wrap and image scaling

Tags: android, html, css, word-wrap

I have a newsletter setup which when i try to test in my Nexus 5 or an other Android device with chrome installed, the content crosses the viewport boundary to give me a horizontal scroll.

Whereas when i open the same mail with gmail app on the device, i see no issues at all and the text wraps properly and images are also scaled properly,

I tried setting up the meta tags with various other combinations but i havent found anything to work for me including mediaqueries.

Can any one help me find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
max-width: 100%;
```

in conjunction with using border-box sizing?

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Let me know if that works for you.